# How can I return 3 degrees of precision from oracle number?

Tags: oracle

We have a scientific application that is in Access and I migrating to Oracle.  Access datatype is Number.  Oracle is number (20,12).

The data is small numbers that we what to show to user in a report as 1.000 E-5 for example.

However the number is actually something like 0.0000099999 which is 0.99999 E-5.

I can convert the number to scientific notation but it returns 0.99999 E-5 without rounding.  I'd like to be able to round this number.  Unfortunately the numbers are all over in terms of # of decimal points.  For example:

0.9999E-5

0.9999E-10

So just a straight ROUND(N,X) would not work I think.  I want to both round to 3 decimals and show in scientific notation.  Essentially this is the scientific concept of degrees of precision where the # of decimals varies but your # of significant figures is always 3.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you want?

```
select to_char(0.0000099999 , '9.999EEEE') from dual
```

1.000E-05

```
select to_char(0.0000000000099999 , '9.999EEEE') from dual
```

1.000E-11

Comment: You need to know how many digits the number is though, and the point is they are all variable.    So I could have 0.999 and 0.00009999.

Comment: @rob  Not sure I understand.  to_char(0.999 , '9.999EEEE')  returns  " 9.990E-01"  . Isnt that what you want?

Comment: Yes but I need to round it as well.  Input:   0.00009999   Desired output 1.00E-05.  I can round but I am not sure how to get around the variable data.  Sometimes it's 0.99, sometimes its 0.00000999  for example.

Comment: @Rob just clarifying, so you need to round all numbers?

if so, the output would be .. 
0.00009999 =>   1.000E-04   and   
0.0009999 =>   1.000E-03   and   
0.009999 =>   1.000E-02   and   
0.09999 =>   1.000E-01   and   
0.9999 =>   1.000E-00      
and so on ... is that what you expect?

Answer (score 0):

If every number needs to be rounded (based on your latest comment) I'm assuming the expected output would be as follows:

0.00009999 => 1.000E-04 
0.0009999 => 1.000E-03 
0.009999 => 1.000E-02 
0.09999 => 1.000E-01 
0.9999 => 1.000E-00

If so, please try : 
`select to_char(round(<input>,abs(trunc(log(10,<input>)))),'0.999EEEE') from dual`

Example :

`select to_char(round(0.00009999,abs(trunc(log(10,0.00009999)))),'0.999EEEE') from dual`

Output :

`1.000E-04`